# Phone uApp versus Ubuntu Store

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-touch, phone

I did have buy an Ubuntu Phone. I saw a lot of applications in uApp (https://uappexplorer.com) that I have interest. Terminal for example (https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.terminal). But when I click on the Install button it sent me to Ubuntu Store (for Ubuntu Phone) and the app is not there. Whats wrong? The App was no created for Ubuntu Phone? Just for other devices?

Comment: For installing terminal you might need to update to the latest system update first as explained here https://askubuntu.com/questions/684988/cant-find-terminal-app-in-ubuntu-store

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu store is the official appstore for Ubuntu touch. You should download apps from there. The uAppExplorer is an unofficial browser for the apps. You can get information and ratings there.

As stated in the FAQ of uAppExplorer:

> What is this site?
>
> This site is an unofficial app browser for Ubuntu Touch apps. All data for 
>   the apps comes from a publicly accessible api. This site is maintained by 
>   Brian Douglass and is not endorsed by or affiliated with Ubuntu or Canonical. 
>   Ubuntu and Canonical are registered trademarks of Canonical Ltd.
>
> How do I install apps?
>
> To install an app, visit this site on your Ubuntu Touch device. Find the
>   app that you wish to install and click the "Install" button. You will then be taken to the official appstore on your device where you can install the app.
>
> Apps are not installed via this site, but via the official appstore.

---

And for the second part of your question:

You should be able to find the terminal app by searching for "Terminal" in the Ubuntu appstore on your phone.